# How to get rid of duplicate records

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Hi I have created one below query and I am facing issue

**SqlQuery**

```
;with tbl as
(
select ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by oi.Name,T.gwtxid order by o.order_id desc) as number,
isnull(oi.Name,'') AS 'Name'
,isnull(T.gwtxid,'') as 'gwtxid'
FROM ORDERS o
INNER JOIN 
ORDERITEMS oi on o.Order_ID=oi.Order_ID
left JOIN 
PAYMENTS P on p.Order_ID=o.Order_ID    
left JOIN 
TRANSACTIONS T ON T.Transaction_ID=P.Transaction_ID    
WHERE O.TOTALCHARGES>0 and o.OrderNumber is not null and o.Order_ID=195180046

)
select * from tbl where  number=1
```

And My record seems to be as below **Table structure**

```
Number   Name           gwtxid  
1      Skunk2 Lower   00WA90298MF810153R
1      Skunk2 Lower   03GF53362DR764524D
1      CA_Taxable     3GF53362DR764524D
1      CA_Taxable     0WA90298MF810153R
1      UPS Ground      0WA90298MF810153R
1      UPS Ground      3GF53362DR764524D
```

I just need uniqueness for name and then transaction id can be repeated

Below is my requirement some thing as **Required Table structure**

```
Name              gwtxid  
Skunk2 Lower      03GF53362DR764524D
CA_Taxable        0WA90298MF810153R
UPS Ground
```

Edited  **Required Table structure** where gwtxid is repeated can also be fine

```
Name              gwtxid  
Skunk2 Lower      03GF53362DR764524D
CA_Taxable        0WA90298MF810153R
UPS Ground        03GF53362DR764524D
```

Can any one help me out from this, I had tried using the rownumber() and it is giving wrong records

Comment: how did you pick what gwtxid goes with each record?

Comment: actually its an transaction id from transaction table and name is the product name from OrderItem table actually I want them both to come and get ,erge in sql.

Comment: @scsimon any idea how can I get this?

Comment: so it doesn't matter which gwtxid you return for each name?

Comment: @scsimon yes doesnt matter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MSDN SELECT - OVER Clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

> (`PARTITION BY` clause) Divides the query result set into partitions. The window function is
>   applied to each partition separately and computation restarts for each
>   partition.

In you case:
`partition by oi.Name,T.gwtxid` gives you these groups/partitions:

```
Group #
1      Skunk2 Lower   00WA90298MF810153R
2      Skunk2 Lower   03GF53362DR764524D
3      CA_Taxable     3GF53362DR764524D
4      CA_Taxable     0WA90298MF810153R
5      UPS Ground      0WA90298MF810153R
6      UPS Ground      3GF53362DR764524D
```

Since each group in your example only contains one row, you get `number` = 1 for every record.

If you change to `partition by oi.Name` then you get the following groups:

```
Group #
1      Skunk2 Lower   00WA90298MF810153R
1      Skunk2 Lower   03GF53362DR764524D
2      CA_Taxable     3GF53362DR764524D
2      CA_Taxable     0WA90298MF810153R
3      UPS Ground      0WA90298MF810153R
3      UPS Ground      3GF53362DR764524D
```

Then you should get the answer you are looking for.